# Find the value of this infinite term

Tags: limits, continued-fractions

[image] goes on till infinity.

I get two solutions by rewriting the term in the form of the equation $x = 3-(2/x)$, which are $1$ and $2$.

But in my opinion this term should have only one possible value. Then which one is wrong and why?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't converge, but instead alternates around two poles $1$ and $2$?

Comment: Maybe, but I haven't ever seen such cases. Can you please give me another example, where the final value keeps "jumping" among certain fixed values?

Comment: Seems like the answers cleared that up :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you continue adding numbers to the expression one at a time, then you have the sequence
$$
3,\; 3-2,\; 3-\frac{2}{3},\; 3-\frac{2}{3-2},\; 3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3}},\; 3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-2}},\;3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3}}}\ldots,
$$
or
$$
3,\; 1,\; \frac{7}{3},\; 1,\; \frac{15}{7},\; 1,\;\frac{31}{15},\;\ldots,
$$
which consists of two alternating subsequences: one is identically $1$, and the other converges to $2$.  Depending on exactly how you define the value of the infinite fraction (i.e., what sequence you define it to be the limit of), it could be $1$, or $2$, or non-convergent.

Comment: You might be interested in some other aspects I mention in my answer. Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Look at it as two different series and you will understand why both 1 and 2 are possible solutions of this:

series 1: $\{3-2, 3-\frac{2}{3-2}, 3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-2}}, ...\}$ 
series 2: $\{3-\frac{2}{3}, 3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3}}, 3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3-\frac{2}{3}}}, ...\}$.

series 1 converges to 1 whereas series 2 converges to 2.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note:** OP's expression is usually regarded as *continued fraction*. We will show it has the **single solution** $2$.

Before we analyse OPs expression, let's have a look at a *continued fraction representation* of $\sqrt{2}$

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{2}=[1;2,2,2,\ldots]=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\ddots}}}
\end{align*}

The convenient notation $[1;2,2,2,\ldots]$ shows the integer part $1$ of $\sqrt{2}$ in the first position, followed by the successive values $2$ in the denominators left from the '$+$' sign.

Since the numerator is always $1$ it's called a *[simple continued fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleContinuedFraction.html)*. In general a simple continued fraction can be written as

\begin{align*}
x=[a_0;a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots]=a_0+\frac{1}{a_1+\frac{1}{a_2+\frac{1}{a_3+\ddots}}}
\end{align*}

The *approximation* by *finite continued fractions* of $x$ is the sequence
\begin{align*}
[a_0],[a_0;a_1],[a_0;a_1,a_2],[a_0;a_1,a_2,a_3],\ldots
\end{align*}

In case of $\sqrt{2}$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
[a_0]&=[1]=1\\
[a_0;a_1]&=[1;2]=1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}\\
[a_0;a_1,a_2]&=[1;2,2]=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{7}{5}\\
[a_0;a_1,a_2,a_3]&=[1;2,2,2]=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{17}{12}\\
&\ldots
\end{align*}

In general we consider a *[continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_faction)* in the form

\begin{align*}
x=a_0+\frac{b_1}{a_1+\frac{b_2}{a_2+\frac{b_3}{a_3+\ddots}}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

and the approximation of $x$ is analogously

\begin{align*}
x_0&=a_0\\
x_1&=a_0+\frac{\left.b_1\right|}{\left|a_1\right.}=a_0+\frac{b_1}{a_1}\\
x_2&=a_0+\frac{\left.b_1\right|}{\left|a_1\right.}
+\frac{\left.b_2\right|}{\left|a_2\right.}
=a_0+\frac{b_1}{a_1+\frac{b_2}{a_2}}\\
x_3&=a_0+\frac{\left.b_1\right|}{\left|a_1\right.}
+\frac{\left.b_2\right|}{\left|a_2\right.}
+\frac{\left.b_3\right|}{\left|a_3\right.}
=a_0+\frac{b_1}{a_1+\frac{b_2}{a_2+\frac{b_3}{a_3}}}\\
&\ldots
\end{align*}

> Now we are well prepared to take a look at OPs expression
>
> \begin{align*}
> x=3+\frac{-2}{3+\frac{-2}{3+\frac{-2}{3+\ddots}}}
> \end{align*}
>
> Here we put the '$-$' sign to the denominator in order to get the same representation as in (1). In a more compact way we can write
>
> \begin{align*}
> x=3+\frac{\left.-2\right|}{\left|3\right.}
> +\frac{\left.-2\right|}{\left|3\right.}
> +\frac{\left.-2\right|}{\left|3\right.}
> +\cdots
> \end{align*}
>
> The approximation of $x$ by its *finite continued fractions* is
>
> \begin{align*}
> x_0&=3\\
> x_1&=3+\frac{\left.-2\right|}{\left|3\right.}=3+\frac{-2}{3}=\frac{7}{3}\\
> x_2&=3+\frac{\left.-2\right|}{\left|3\right.}
> +\frac{\left.-2\right|}{\left|3\right.}
> =3+\frac{-2}{3}=\frac{15}{7}\\
> x_3&=3+\frac{\left.-2\right|}{\left|3\right.}
> +\frac{\left.-2\right|}{\left|3\right.}
> +\frac{\left.-2\right|}{\left|3\right.}
> =3+\frac{-2}{3+\frac{-2}{3+\frac{-2}{3}}}=\frac{31}{15}\tag{2}\\
> &\ldots
> \end{align*}
>
> We see from (2) that $x$ converges to $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(2+\frac{1}{n}\right)=2$ which is easily to prove.
>
> **Conclusion**: The infinite continued fraction $x$ is defined as the limit of the corresponding approximating finite continued fractions in (2) and we so obtain  $x=2$ as the only solution.

*Epilog:* Another nice gem is the continued fraction of $e$

\begin{align*}
e=[2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,...]
\end{align*}

and here is a *[short proof](http://www.cimpa-icpam.org/archivesecoles/20100122170225/0601660.pdf)* of it.